# Mysql 5.5 database charset issue. Database charset changes from utf8 to latin1

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, collation

I have a problem with mysql 5.5. When I type in the console

```
 show variables like 'char%';
 show variables like 'collation%';
```

my output is as it should be

```
character_set_database   | utf8


collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci
```

When I change to a database with use Final; for example, the character set and collation change to latin1. I need utf8 because I want to store data in greek and with the change all entries are with '?'. Do I do something wrong? And when yes, how do I change it in order to use all the time utf8?

I create the database and the tables with the code below:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS FinalEssay
CHARACTER SET utf8 
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Department` 
(
  `deptid` INT(6) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `schoolid` INT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deptid`) 
)
ENGINE = InnoDB,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Would appreciate it if someone could help me.